# Significance of 2 Teveis in Judaism

Tags: jewish-date-series, history, calendar

Is the 2nd day of the Month of Teveis significant in Judaism? Looking for answers as to what characteristics (historical, numerological or otherwise) that is commemorated by or significant to Judaism on this date. It can include both positive and negative significance. It can also include Yarzheits of well known personalities that are themselves significant to Judaism, or milestones in their lives (such as birthdays) that are currently or were celebrated within Judaism.

**Please cite / link your sources, if possible.**

All interesting answers will be up voted. Best answer will be accepted.

Comment: See http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1600.

Comment: See http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3383/440 for why this post was changed.

Comment: Why are birthdays of well known personalities ok?

Comment: Neither of the currently posted answers are valid under these edits. @Yishai

Comment: @DoubleAA, are those answers potential answers to an on scope question? I think yartzeits or birthdays of such people may be commemorated, or commemoratable, and of interest to jewish learning in any event.

Comment: @Yishai If they are commemorated, the answer must say so. Pretty simple. It's the religious commemoration which is the answer. (I imagine that is easily accomplished for most Yartzeits.) It's no different than Alex's current answer: it's valid if he demonstrates that Lubavitchers (or some other [sub]group) celebrate the listed salvation.

Comment: @DoubleAA, My goal is to make an as broad as possible question that is in-scope. I'm thinking that someone might want to know about a Yartzeit or Birthday as a legitimate Jewish question, even if it isn't currently commemorated. For example, no one to my knowledge commemorated the Rambam's birthday until the Lubavitcher Rebbe set up the first cycle of Rambam study to complete on that date, but even without that having been done (yet) knowing the Birthday of such a person would be of Jewish interest (it seems to me).

Comment: @Yishai I think we generally disallow requests for random biographical details about rabbis without explicit Judaism motivation. I think the Rebbe could make the Rambam's birthday into a Judaism fact, just as he could make a dollar into a Judaism artifact, but except in the context of his having done so (or some similar conference of significance), they're not *a priori* about Judaism.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, I think in this case it can allow people to learn about Rabbis they didn't know about. I could see dropping birthdays though, as they often aren't celebrated, and if someone's birthday is known their yartzeit is almost certainly known as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On 2 Teves 5700, R' Yosef Yitzchak Schneersohn, the sixth Lubavitcher Rebbe, was rescued from Nazi-occupied Warsaw (and eventually, a few months later, reached the United States).

Answer (score 2):

The second of Teves 5613 (1752) is the Yartzeit of Yaakov Ibn Tzur, a Morrocan Rav and Kabbalist.

More about his life [here](http://www.mytzadik.com/index.asp?lid=6&page=tzadik&kid=371). Note that it lists his Yartzeit as 1 Teves, but says he passed away on Shabbos night. [That year](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%94'%D7%AA%D7%A7%D7%99%22%D7%92) Shabbos night was 2 Teves.

He is the author of several Piyutim, as well as the responsa [משפט וצדקה ביעקב](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/1107).

Comment: Maybe they meant erev Shabbas?

Comment: Hebrew Wikipedia supports the 2 Teves date.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Luach Dvar B'Itoh תשע"א](http://hebrewbooks.org/51553) Page 452:

- 2nd day of the Month of Teveis is sometimes זאת חנוכה. (other years it's the 7th day of Chanuka)

  - The last day of Chanuka is the last day in the year one can bring Bikurim - albeit without a Bracha since it's after Sukkoth. ([ביכורים א, ו](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00963.html#HtmpReportNum0005_L2)).
- Yahrzeit of  יעקב צבי בן יהושע אשר רבינוביץ מפוריסוב, the author of the [עטרה לראש צדיק](http://hebrewbooks.org/3658). Died in תרמ"ט.

Answer (score 1):

2 Teveis - December 15, 1947 the Jordanians laid siege to Yerushalayim